# Probability with same number of heads and tails

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this question that I don't know where to begin, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Consider the following random experiment. Toss a coin until the same number of heads and tails have been observed. Take as random variable, X, the observed number of heads (or tails). Determine the first few values in the probability distribution and calculate

$\sum^{5}_{n=1} nP (X = n)$

I'm not sure exactly where to start, if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't differentiate between $H$ and $T$, denote the fist tossed coin $\alpha$, because it doesn't matter what you've tossed. Then you're either done w.p $\frac{1}{2}$ by tossing $\alpha^c$ (NOT alpha) or you return to the state $\alpha$ w.p. $\frac{1}{2}$. Hence you get $P(X=1)$ w.p. $\frac{1}{2}$. Can you hande from here?

Comment: P(X = 1) = 1/2
P(X = 2) = 1/4
P(X = 3) = 1/8 ..?

Am I on the right track? The limit will reach 0?

Comment: do you need the same #H/T or the same #H/T in a row?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not exactly sure what you're asking?

I'm pretty sure it's just the same number of H/T in general, doesn't have to be in a row

Comment: In this case if you toss $\alpha^c$ straight away, you are done; if you toss another $\alpha$, the only way to get $X=2$ is to toss two $\alpha^c$ in a row - otherwise you'll need one more $\alpha^c$. Hence in order to get $k=2$ you need $\alpha \alpha, \alpha^c, \alpha^c$. Things would be different but for the 'Toss a coin until the same number of heads and tails have been observed' condition.